# CakePHP HABTM relationship saving new associations

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.3

Im having some problems with saving my HABTM relationship for some code I'm working with.  I have `Podcasts` and `Categories` in a HABTM relationship.  Code and problem explanation below

**Model/Podcast.php**

```
class Podcast extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = 'Episode';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Category' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Category',
                'joinTable' => 'categories_podcasts',
                'foreignKey' => 'podcast_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'category_id',
                'unique' => false
            )
        );
}
```

**Model/Category.php**

```
class Category extends AppModel{
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Podcast' =>
            array(
                'className' => 'Podcast',
                'joinTable' => 'categories_podcasts',
                'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'podcast_id',
                'unique' => false
            )
        );
}
```

This is what the array I'm passing into `saveAll()` looks like

```
Array
(
    [Podcast] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mohr Stories - FakeMustache.com
            [description] => Join your host Jay Mohr and a rotating cast of his hilarious friends as they regale you with tales and conversation covering every topic imaginable. You haven't heard the half of it until you've heard... Mohr Stories.
            [website] => http://www.FakeMustache.com
        )

    [Category] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
    )

)
```

Which works fine - the podcast is added and the join table is updated, but I was under the impression that my `Category` array could look like the following:

```
 [Category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test2
                )

        )
```

Which would save the new categories "Test" and "Test2" and then update the join table with their newly added ids.  Is this not possible, or I am missing some of the picture here?

Comment: `I was under the impression` - based on what documentation?

Comment: Based on [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) of the Saving Your Data page of the docs. Their example array there and the description _"Passing the above array to saveAll() will create the contained tags, each associated with their respective recipes."_

Answer (score 0):

You do are able to do that, but with another data format in which each record contains the associated data as on the following code that allows to save 2 records :

```
array{
    array{
        'Podcast' => array {
             'id' => 25
         },
         'Category' => array {
             'name' => 'Test'
         }
    }
    array{
         'Podcast' => array {
             'id' => 25
         },
         'Category' => array {
             'name' => 'Test2'
         }
    }
}
```

Pass this array to the saveAll method on one of your Podcast/Category Models.

```
$this->Podcast->saveAll($myData);
```

But take care, **as you don't provide any id for the categories, they will be created**, even if there are existing Category with the same name.

And **if a Podcast with the id 25 doesn't exists, it will be created**.